# can't find the symfony demo routing system?

Tags: symfony

I installed the Symfony demo sample and looked to it's code.
but I cant't found how its routing worked.
no routing definition found on the source code.
I installed  the Symfony 4.1 version.

I know how symfony routing work but in symfony demo sample I can't find the routing for add,delete,edit and show content.
I don't know how it defined .
I search the entire source and can't find them .
when I looked to the routes.yaml I just saw the bellow code:
homepage:
    path: /{_locale}
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController::templateAction
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
        template: default/homepage.html.twig
        _locale: '%locale%'

but when I searched in the project in the cache I saw the bellow code and didn't understood how it created.

```
   'admin_index' => array(array('_locale'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\BlogController::index', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/admin/post/'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'admin_post_index' => array(array('_locale'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\BlogController::index', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/admin/post/'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'admin_post_new' => array(array('_locale'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\BlogController::new', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/admin/post/new'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'admin_post_show' => array(array('_locale', 'id'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\BlogController::show', '_locale' => 'en'), array('id' => '\\d+', '_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('variable', '/', '\\d+', 'id'), array('text', '/admin/post'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'admin_post_edit' => array(array('_locale', 'id'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\BlogController::edit', '_locale' => 'en'), array('id' => '\\d+', '_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/edit'), array('variable', '/', '\\d+', 'id'), array('text', '/admin/post'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'admin_post_delete' => array(array('_locale', 'id'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\Admin\\BlogController::delete', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/delete'), array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'id'), array('text', '/admin/post'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'blog_index' => array(array('_locale'), array('page' => '1', '_format' => 'html', '_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\BlogController::index2', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/blog/'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'blog_rss' => array(array('_locale'), array('page' => '1', '_format' => 'xml', '_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\BlogController::index2', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/blog/rss.xml'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'blog_index_paginated' => array(array('_locale', 'page'), array('_format' => 'html', '_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\BlogController::index2', '_locale' => 'en'), array('page' => '[1-9]\\d*', '_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('variable', '/', '[1-9]\\d*', 'page'), array('text', '/blog/page'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'blog_post' => array(array('_locale', 'slug'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\BlogController::postShow', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'slug'), array('text', '/blog/posts'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'comment_new' => array(array('_locale', 'postSlug'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\BlogController::commentNew', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/new'), array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'postSlug'), array('text', '/blog/comment'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'blog_search' => array(array('_locale'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\BlogController::search', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/blog/search'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'security_login' => array(array('_locale'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/login'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    'security_logout' => array(array('_locale'), array('_controller' => 'App\\Controller\\SecurityController::logout', '_locale' => 'en'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('text', '/logout'), array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
    '_twig_error_test' => array(array('code', '_format'), array('_controller' => 'twig.controller.preview_error::previewErrorPageAction', '_format' => 'html'), array('code' => '\\d+'), array(array('variable', '.', '[^/]++', '_format'), array('variable', '/', '\\d+', 'code'), array('text', '/_error')), array(), array()),
    '_wdt' => array(array('token'), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction'), array(), array(array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'token'), array('text', '/_wdt')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_home' => array(array(), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::homeAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/_profiler/')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_search' => array(array(), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::searchAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/_profiler/search')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_search_bar' => array(array(), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::searchBarAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/_profiler/search_bar')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_phpinfo' => array(array(), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::phpinfoAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/_profiler/phpinfo')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_search_results' => array(array('token'), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::searchResultsAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/search/results'), array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'token'), array('text', '/_profiler')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_open_file' => array(array(), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::openAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/_profiler/open')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler' => array(array('token'), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.profiler::panelAction'), array(), array(array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'token'), array('text', '/_profiler')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_router' => array(array('token'), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.router::panelAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/router'), array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'token'), array('text', '/_profiler')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_exception' => array(array('token'), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.exception::showAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/exception'), array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'token'), array('text', '/_profiler')), array(), array()),
    '_profiler_exception_css' => array(array('token'), array('_controller' => 'web_profiler.controller.exception::cssAction'), array(), array(array('text', '/exception.css'), array('variable', '/', '[^/]++', 'token'), array('text', '/_profiler')), array(), array()),
    'homepage' => array(array('_locale'), array('template' => 'default/homepage.html.twig', '_locale' => 'en', '_controller' => 'Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\TemplateController::templateAction'), array('_locale' => 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN'), array(array('variable', '/', 'en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN', '_locale')), array(), array()),
```

thanks

Comment: [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony 4.1 routing is defined directly in controllers with annotation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

In your case, you can find routing for add, delete, edit and show directly above each actions:
https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/src/Controller/BlogController.php